# server terminates connection on listdirectories commons.net.ftpclient

Tags: java, ftp-client, filezilla

I am using a filezilla ftp server and commons.net.ftpclient to access it from java. I create a connection and login successfully, but when i try to list the directories of the current working directory, the server terminates the connection. I've tried all the active and passive modes but the same issue arises due to which my connection gets terminated. I've also given the user created on the server full previlidges on the shared directory and that didn't fix anything. The code is very straight forward so im not posting it. Am i missing something in the flow?

Thanks.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393545/how-can-i-access-an-ftp-server-with-jsch/44538830#44538830 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200106/urlconnection-ftp-list-files

Comment: Show us server log file. Show us Java exception and its stack trace. Or even better a packet capture of the session (e.g. using Wireshark). Basically, show us anything, otherwise we cannot help you.